# Short story about a robot who wants to become a writer

Tags: story-identification, robots, isaac-asimov

I don't remember much about it, but I remember reading it about 5-8 years ago while on an Asimov kick. It may be one of his stories, but I can't remember names/places.

All I can remember is that the main character, a robot, decides that he wants to become an author and experiences opposition to his claims that a machine can be creative.

Any help?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is very likely [Cal](http://www.asimovreviews.net/Stories/Story419.html), a short story from 1991.

> CL-123X, aka “Cal,” is a robot owned by a writer. As an experiment, the writer begins giving Cal himself the ability to write. From clumsy and hesitant beginnings, Cal’s understanding of humanity and skill as a writer grow apace until he becomes too aware of mankind and too cynical. His owner decides to call the experiment off—but it’s too late, as Cal has found a driving force more fundamental even than the Laws of Robotics.

It could be [The Bicentennial Man](http://www.asimovreviews.net/Stories/Story015.html), but the description doesn't seem to match that too much.

Comment: I agree it sounds like Cal. The Bicentennial Man wanted to become an artist and I believe had lots of success selling wood carvings.